# SES sending Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am sending a mail through ses in nodejs.

```
exports.sendEmail = async () => {
const SESConfig = {
  accessKeyId: "xxxxxxx",
  accessSecretKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  region: "us-east-1",
}
AWS.config.update(SESConfig);

// Create sendEmail params
var params = {
  Destination: {
    ToAddresses: [
      "xxx@xxx.xxx",
      /* more items */
    ],
  },
  Message: {
    /* required */
    Body: {          Text: {
        Charset: "UTF-8",
        Data: "TEXT_FORMAT_BODY",
      },
    },
    Subject: {
      Charset: "UTF-8",
      Data: "Test email",
    },
  },
  Source: "xxx@xxx.xxx" /* required */,
};

var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
  .sendEmail(params)
  .promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
await sendPromise
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('err', data)
    console.log(data.MessageId);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('err', err)
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });
};
```

When i call this function in my api then it's saying **Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1**
I had added same mail in from and to which is verified on aws ses

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.